# Does Visual Studio 2019 support 64 bit custom visualizer?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a special type to display but the type require a 64bit dll thus I have to compile the custom visualizer in x64. However I got bad image error when viewing the variable. Does visual studio 2019 support for visualizer compile in 64 bit mode? Or because VS is 32 bit program thus the visualizer also require to be 32 bit?

Comment: [This problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/visual-cpp-custom-visualizer-compatibility?view=vs-2019) sounds like an opportunity.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like only support for c++ project. I need custom visualizer for c#.

Comment: Doesn't make much sense, a C# visualizer can run in any bitness.  Do make sure to remove the jitter overrides in Project > Properties > Build tab.  Platform = AnyCPU, Prefer 32-bit unticked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Visual Studio IDE is 32bit (and because of the many existing extensions and the long history of the Visual Studio IDE this is not going to chance easily).

So any extensions, including custom visualisers, need to be 32bit.

If you cannot get a 32bit build of your dll, then you would need to have some kind of container process and then communicate with that (this is unlikely to be easy, because none of the internal APIs would be accessible to the helper process).